# How to Restore Previous Desktop Theme after Windows 10 1903 Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, desktop, windows-10-upgrade

I just installed the Windows 10 1903 Feature Upgrade.   My desktop is now a bright light blue.  I want the previous theme back.  I looked at themes and backgrounds, and there's very little there, and the previous option is gone.

Has anyone figured out how to get the previous desktop background back?  (The standard one, from pre-1903 Windows 10).

Thanks.

Comment: There are 6 default themes in V1903: 3 Blue, 1 Sunset, 1 Flower, 1 Rock theme.  Do you have these?  They are not all Blue. Is your background set to solid colour?

Comment: We don’t know what theme you were using.  Can you provide more details?

Comment: You can Add themes, select W10 from the drop down menu>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13768/desktop-themes-featured

Comment: Many, many more on this page, again pick W10 from the drop down menu>>>>>>>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14014/windows-desktop-themes-from-the-community